# iOS native web app & audio stream

Tags: ios, html, audio, web, streaming

I'm currently building a web application that will have a live streaming function (I'm using the HTML5 audio object for this). I would like to offer the ability to run this website as a native web app on iOS devices. The problem is that when you minimize the native app the audio stream is stopped, also re-opening the "app" will create a page reload. Has anyone found a way around this issue?

Comment: So you have a html5 app embedded in your native app in a webview? I think the only way to have background audio is to use Background Tasks as described by Apple [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24), but obviously you can't do that with html. You'd have to make the audio player native...

Comment: Yes I noticed that too. Unfortunately building a native app is not really an option. Will have to run it without the native view then. Thanks for you response.

Comment: If it's html5 embedded in a native app you could make just the audio-player part native...

Answer (score 0):

You could use [appMobi](http://dev.appmobi.com/).  You would have to add some logic to switch between the Audio object and the appMobi.player object, but it should be straightforward if all you want is for audio to play in the background of the native app.